# Why search for theoretical particle?

Tags: soft-question, large-hadron-collider, higgs

Just out of curiosity, is there any special purpose in human life, the search for some theoretical particle for its uncertain benefit, to prove theory of everything which doesn't serve any advancement towards humanity (yet), using huge amount of resources which is better of allocated to fund research for alternative renewable energy?

To enable warp drive? Anti-matter as alternate fuel? To know the ultimate answer of universe, life and everything?

Comment: Dear @Daniel Leung, what exactly is Your purpose to come on this science/physics site? You obviously dont appreciate or consider "knowledge" and "understanding how our physical world works" as a "benefit". This question is quit insulting to a lot of good and hard working physicists.

Comment: One could argue that this question deserves to be closed according to 4 out of 5 criteria in the list. But before we may meaningfully answer, I would like to know what kind of an answer we should be trying to offer. So let me ask Daniel Leung: Just out of curiosity, what is the purpose of your life, something that consumes place on Earth and resources that could be much more meaningfully used for scientific research, for people who actually create some values? Does your life allow me to learn the shape of the hidden Calabi-Yau dimensions? Build a stronger accelerator? Or something else?

Comment: And why people do science at all? For fun, obviously (-;

Answer (score 4):

The electron was identified as a particle in 1897 by J. J. Thomson, and yet at that time none of the world knew what could be useful that particle for and why Thomson had been really working on that spending time and money. Now please just look at the planet we live on and compare the progress since 1897. That particle called electron changed completely the face and life on earth, sure nobody says Higgs would do the the same but the answers about the universe surely will change and does now the life on earth. I would suggest you to watch the documentary narrated by  [Carl Sagan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos%3a_A_Personal_Voyage)  "**A Personal Voyage**". You question as a taxpayer is asked many times before and Carl Sagan gave a satisfying answer. Science seeks the answers for the life, universe and how it works. In time answers embodies in life on earth as new gadgets,  inventions and technological improvements, this is how it works.

Comment: +1 for giving a considered answer to what was basically a trolling question.